# Error messages at boot, what they mean and how can I fix them

Tags: boot

Any assistance understanding what these messages mean and how I can fix them will be appreciated, **Dell XPS 15 9510 - BIOS = 1.4.0**

[image]

Comment: Those error messages about ACPI can usually be ignored if the system boots and works as expected. They are unrelated to the OS. Update UEFI.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: Added the requested information, thank you

Comment: Your BIOS is current. Enter your BIOS, note what the crucial settings are, then find/select the "Reset to factory defaults". See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 21.04, and I had installed Kernel 5.13, I went back to the original Kernel 5.11 and all the messages went away, I am going to wait for 21.10 with the newer Kernel.